# API in python send base64 encoded file to php

Tags: python, php, symfony

My goal is to send a json with encoded file to a Symfony app,

here my API code :

```
base64_attachment = base64.encodebytes(att.payload)
arr["attachments"][att.filename] = base64_attachment
```

and PHP :

```
$file = base64_decode($attachment);
$fileName = $k;
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", $fileName);

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "wr+");
fwrite($handle, $file);
$file=fread($handle, filesize($tmpfname));
var_dump($file);
```

but after decode, the value are not good and cannot be save in a file...
get this return on var_dump

> string(0) ""

Comment: I don't know anything about python, but you are passing the base64 encoded string to a parameter called `att.filename` which does not seem correct to me

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't specify, att.filename is the name of the file, 
after converting to json it's something like that {"attachments": {
   "file_name.ext": "iVBORw0KGgoAAA..."}}

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump(base64_decode($attachment))`?

Comment: If you want to read what you've written to the file without opening a new handle, then you need to `rewind($handle);` before the read.

Comment: Yes, I just try ` var_dump(base64_decode($attachment))` it don't work for me... I'm not sure there is a compatibilité between python and php on this case

Comment: wvar_dump give me this '�PNG  IHDR� WO7q�zTXtRaw profile type exifxڭ�ird�n��s^'pXA�ށ��T�Z���_��UJ��H� �?�}��UR�Jm����μ�aį����X�����?K��s����~�_����ک�Tr��J|��� ���e�^�^���9����?+� �m��=Ɵ����?�?W?��/~^�3ʟj�>5⇿� ���....'

Comment: Thanks a lot, rewind is working, all is save and I can access to it ! I have still a problem, this value can't be decode to an img [base64.guru](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image) but its an other problem !